# Animated multicell formula array for Excel VBA only returns 0's?

Tags: excel, vba

It looks like a simple enough code to me, but I can't get it to work properly. I'm trying to iterate through rows of values in order to add them one at a time to a display row, storing the previous value in an extra row in order to avoid circular calculations.

The WriteRow loads properly on the first iteration, but after that all results in the WriteRow and StoreRow are 0.

Here's the code:

```
    Const StartRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRow As Long = 367
    Const StoreRow As Long = 369
    Const WriteRow As Long = 370
    Dim RowNumber As Long
    
    Range("A" & StoreRow, "T" & StoreRow).ClearContents
    Range("A" & WriteRow, "T" & WriteRow).ClearContents
    DoEvents
    Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
    
    For RowNumber = StartRow To LastRow
        DoEvents
        Range("A" & WriteRow, "T" & WriteRow).FormulaArray = "=A" & StoreRow & ":T" & StoreRow & "+A" & RowNumber & ":T" & RowNumber
        Range("A" & StoreRow, "T" & StoreRow).FormulaArray = "=A" & WriteRow & ":T" & WriteRow
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
        DoEvents
    Next RowNumber
    
    
End Sub
```

I did also try adding `Range("A" & WriteRow, "T" & WriteRow).AutoFill Destination:=Range("A" & WriteRow & ":T" & WriteRow)`, but the AutoFill kept failing. The formula bar shows "{=A370:T370}" for StoreRow and "{=A369:T369+A2:T2}" for WriteRow.

I think the problem is that there's still a circular reference. Is there a good way to get around it?

Comment: With full confidence, I can assure that you do not need to do `Application.Wait` or `DoEvents` after `.ClearContents`. The application will not have any erroneous values leak in to later steps.

Comment: One of your arrayformula lines has no changing element despite being inside the loop:`Range("A" & StoreRow, "T" & StoreRow).FormulaArray = "=A" & WriteRow & ":T" & WriteRow`. If it is not intended to change, I suggest moving this line outside the loop.

Comment: Your other arrayformula line doesn't change which range the formula is put into, meaning every iteration of the loop aside from the last is overwritten by the last iteration. So if it runs from `RowNumber = 2 To 367` the only result you will see is from `RowNumber = 367` and all other results are overwritten.

Comment: Copied some things from a website without really understanding VBA, that's where the ```Application.Wait``` and ```DoEvents``` came from, but yes, they're unnecessary. I did intend for the StoreRow to change, it would hold the previous values in the animation. I think I figured out the other issue as well.

Answer (score 0):

Found an answer that produces the results I was looking for:

```
Sub ExpensesChart()
    Const StartRow As Long = 2
    Const LastRow As Long = 367
    Const StoreRow As Long = 369
    Const WriteRow As Long = 370
    Dim RowNumber As Long
    Dim val As Double
    
    
    Range("A" & StoreRow, "T" & StoreRow).ClearContents
    Range("A" & WriteRow, "T" & WriteRow).ClearContents
    
    For RowNumber = StartRow To LastRow
        DoEvents
        Range("A" & WriteRow, "T" & WriteRow).FormulaArray = "=A" & StoreRow & ":T" & StoreRow & "+A" & RowNumber & ":T" & RowNumber
        Range("A" & WriteRow, "T" & WriteRow).Formula = Range("A" & WriteRow, "T" & WriteRow).Value
        Range("A" & StoreRow & ":T" & StoreRow).FormulaArray = Array(Range("A" & WriteRow & ":T" & WriteRow))
        Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("00:00:1"))
        DoEvents
    Next RowNumber
    
    
End Sub
```

Comment: The repeated `Application.Wait` is adding 6 minutes to the macro's runtime. Have you encountered errors when the line is removed? I didn't see any when I ran it in my test document. If you are concerned about it, I would suggest replacing it with the line `ActiveSheet.Calculate`.

Comment: You mentioned in another comment that the third ArrayFormula is meant to be placed in different rows, iterating with the loop, but that is not included in this answer. You would need to include `RowNumber` inside the `Range` expression so the loop can change the address, like `Range("A" & StoreRow + RowNumber ...`

Comment: I did want it to be like an animation, but I also did shorten the wait time. Right now I'm using ```Application.Wait (Now + 0.000005)```. There isn't a third ArrayFormula, only two. On the sheet I have a table of data, one row that I want to display the animated data, and (maybe this is where the third array came from) one to store the previous frame.